# Settings Synchronize button: no user.config files were found in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

It isn't really causing a problem but it is annoying me... Does anyone know how to refresh the locations for your user config in Visual Studio?

When I click the Synchronize button in the Project Properties->Settings form, I get the error message `No user.config files were found in any of the following locations.`

The paths listed do not exist, so I know why the error message is coming up.   However the settings files must be stored under some different paths.

Any ideas? I did do a quick search in the registry for the paths but nothing was real obvious as to what I could delete. Perhaps it's something contained in a file in the solution?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, Windows XP.

Comment: This issue is reported to Microsoft at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Settings-Synchronize-button-deletes-from/10262625.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error, so much as a warning that "There were no files to delete, so nothing was actually done."

From "[Synchronize button on the Settings tab](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/55_2006_3_0_0_729014/Synchronize-button-on-the-Settings-tab.htm)":

> The "Synchronize" button is used to
>   remove the runtime-generated,
>   application-specific user.config files
>   from the disk. If your application
>   doesn't have any user-scoped
>   application settings(that means all
>   the application settings' scope are
>   "Application"), then there would not
>   have a user.config file for the VS2005
>   IDE to delete after run-time.

You would use this button when you change the settings schema between debug sessions, so the versions don't get "out of sync" and cause errors reading from the settings file.

The warning would also, of course, happen the second time you click "Synchronize" in a row.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point of the question -- which isn't that clear, I'd love to fix it but the edit queue is full as usual. The question is saying, 'Why is Visual Studio not finding and deleting the correct user.config files, instead complaining about missing files in the wrong locations?'

Answer (score 5):

I seem to have a problem reseting my settings even if clicking "Synchronize" button. This problem only occurs in Windows 8 OS, but I am not getting any problem in Windows 7. So instead of bumping your head on the wall, I'd like to share this.

Open File Explorer and press CTRL+D or click the bread crumbs bar, and enter "%appdata%" - go back one folder, and open "Local" folder and look for a folder the same name as your project or solution name... and delete that folder.

hope that helps.

-- update --
I'd like to point out that this problem was for Visual Studio 2012 running in Windows 8
.. sorry, didn't saw the date.. this is pretty old.

Comment: My code on Windows 7 wouldn't run out of visual studio--crashed when trying to create the main form. This fixed that problem. The synchronize button still throws this error however.

Answer (score 1):

I never saw this feature work correctly in visual studio since version 2010 up 'till now on my 2013 version. The following locations are empty but the config file really exists somewhere in appdata\local\\.vshost.exe_StrongName_ and followed by a bunch of ciphered characters.

VS always fail to locate this file and apparently MS VS dev. team is not urged to correct that broken thing.

Comment: It is now VS2017 and it still is confusing. Should it work? Should it not?

Comment: I'm currently using VS 2015 Express, and it still fails to find the user.config file that the app creates.  The paths in which it looks do not include the correct location, and I used all the defaults to create my config file, so I can only assume that it is still a bug.

Comment: Meanwhile we have VS 2022 and the issue persists.

Comment: This issue is reported to Microsoft at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Settings-Synchronize-button-deletes-from/10262625. Feel free to upvote there.